# Office 2007 install limits?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I've been able to install Office 2003 on a couple of computers that I own without any trouble.  However, I just got office 2007 and I'm not able to install it on my computer and my laptop.  I know this may violate agreements and whatnot but I'm curious to know if this is something that Microsoft has finally started to crack down on or what.  Any information is help full.

And I know that I'm going to get a few answers telling me that I'm "stealing" or whatever so I don't need to hear about that.  thanks. ;)

Comment: What messages do you get, if any?

Comment: That the number of installs has exceeded the limit.

Answer (score 3):

The number of OEM installations is limited to one computer indeed and the license cannot be transferred, certain retail Office editions allow installations on up 3 computers, IIRC.

If you purchased a retail edition (as opposed to OEM) and the number of maximum installations is reached you may be able to install the software from another computer if you uninstall Office on the other machine. You may have to contact Microsoft and have it activated via phone if the online activation fails.

More information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/FX102464411033.aspx):

> OEM License Terms limit the
>   installation to the device on which
>   the software was pre-installed.

Comment: @AppsByAaron - Then this license will live and die with the computer it is installed on right now. you may be able to reinstall office on the same hardware, but again this may require a chat with a Microsoft rep.

Comment: So could I have avoided all this with a retail box?

Comment: @AppsByAaron - yes, for example, the retail version of MSO 2007 Home/Student can be legally installed on 3 computers.

Comment: I haven't used MS Office in years. There are plenty of cheap/free alternatives that can handle the MS document formats.

Comment: @Kenneth Cochran - while most of them are excellent alternatives, compatibility often leaves to be desired. If compatibility isn't a major concern, they're fine.